# Get the most used and most "different" colors from image

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing

I've been browsing the Web for an algorithm which analyzes an image and returns the most different and used colors -- but with no luck.

For instance;

If I'd have a bitmap with `25% red (255,0,0)` in `RGB`, `50% fully blue (0,0,255)` and `25% pink (255,0,255)`

I would want the algorithm to return these three (or more, depending on avalible colors) colors sorted in the usage, so:

```
1. Blue
2. Red / Pink
3. Red / Pink
```

Anyone know some way I could start this? Maybe some articles to read etc. I've never used images in C# like this.

Comment: Where's the line between most different and most used (i.e. is often used and slightly different or rarely used and very different better)?

Comment: That's only one of the things I'm trying to figure out. If you would have a list of some sort of all the most used colors, you can probably try to distinguish between those in some way..

Comment: The thing is though; if you only take the "most used" colors, you'd probably end up with 50 shades of gray (I did just do that, can't believe it myself)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, this may help you (of course you have to read the data according to your needs then):

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the bitmap image color statistics
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bit">The bitmap image you want to analyze</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<KeyValuePair<Color, int>> GetStatistics(Bitmap bit)
    {
        Dictionary<Color, int> countDictionary = new Dictionary<Color, int>();

        for (int wid = 0; wid < bit.Width; wid++)
        {//for every column in the image
            for (int he = 0; he < bit.Height; he++)
            {//for every row in the image

                //Get the color of the pixel reached (i.e. at the current column and row)
                Color currentColor = bit.GetPixel(wid, he);

                //If a record already exists for this color, set the count, otherwise just set it as 0
                int currentCount = (countDictionary.ContainsKey(currentColor) ? countDictionary[currentColor] : 0);

                if (currentCount == 0)
                {//If this color doesnt already exists in the dictionary, add it
                    countDictionary.Add(currentColor, 1);
                }
                else
                {//If it exists, increment the value and update it
                    countDictionary[currentColor] = currentCount + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        //order the list from most used to least used before returning
        List<KeyValuePair<Color, int>> l = countDictionary.OrderByDescending(o => o.Value).ToList();

        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add some text about this dynamic color list histogram just uncommented code is not worth much for people that do not know the background about it.

Comment: GetPixel is veeeeerrrrrrryyyyyy slooooooowwww http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406045/Why-the-use-of-GetPixel-and-SetPixel-is-so-ineffic

Answer (score 1):

1. **most used colors**

   With a little google effort you would find **Histogram**. If you want to use shades as separate color then you have `256^3` colors. So either use some dynamic list instead or ignore few least significant bits to lower the number a bit. You can also change the dynamic range by normalization of colors.

   - black is black
   - and for everything else change vector size to `Max` for example

     ```
     Max = 2^5-1 = 31
     normalized color = color * Max / |color|
     ```

   Now the algorithm:

   1. create a counter table `cnt` for all combinations of colors

      for `Max = 31` the size would be `2^15 = 32768`. Set the whole table to zero.

      ```
      int cnt[32768];
      for (int i=0;i<32768;i++) cnt[i]=0;
      ```
   2. go through entire image and for each pixel

      - normalize its color
      - convert it to address (for example `adr = (R) | (G<<5) | (B<<10)`)
      - increment its counter `cnt[adr]++;`

   After this you have histogram in `cnt[]`. so now index sort it by value of `cnt` and you have obtained the colors sorted by their usage
2. **most different color**

   How would you define it? I would use data from histogram and do search for `max` distance between 2 colors in it (after normalization)

   ```
   d = |color1 - color2|
   ```

   Do not need to `sqrt` it ... if you use `d^2` you will obtain the same results. Ignore all entries where `cnt[adr]==0` (that is unused color). This is still `O(n^2)` ... more like `~T(n*n/2)` ... in runtime terms but `n` is not the number of pixels in image. instead it is just number of different used colors in image which is far less ... Also after index sort of histogram and removing/ignoring all the `cnt[adr]==0` entries even lover.